# golang undefined module, which is downloaded correctly

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I follow instructions on [kafka go sample project](https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/go/#create-project). After I get module using command

```
go get github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka
```

it appears inside my user directory:

```
C:\Users\fjod\go\pkg\mod\github.com\confluentinc\confluent-kafka-go@v1.9.2
```

Contents of go.mod file:

```
module kafka-go-producer

go 1.20

require github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go v1.9.2
```

When I enter **go list**, I see only my module:

```
go list                                                                                                                  ﳑ in powershell at 11:50:56
kafka-go-producer
```

Project structure:

```
 dir                                                                                                                      ﳑ in powershell at 12:04:11


    Directory: F:\work\kafka\kafka_dotnet_golang\src\golang\kafka-go-producer


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       07.06.2023     11:27                  .idea
-a----       07.06.2023     11:41             93   go.mod
-a----       07.06.2023     11:22          21054   go.sum
-a----       07.06.2023     11:05           1463   producer.go
-a----       07.06.2023     10:43             32   producer.properties
-a----       07.06.2023     10:39            932   util.go
```

On entering **go build** command, I see following errors:

```
go build                                                                                                                 ﳑ in powershell at 11:51:05
# kafka-go-producer
.\util.go:12:42: undefined: kafka.ConfigMap
.\util.go:14:32: undefined: kafka.ConfigValue
.\producer.go:21:18: undefined: kafka.NewProducer
.\producer.go:50:20: undefined: kafka.Message
.\producer.go:51:26: undefined: kafka.TopicPartition
.\producer.go:51:73: undefined: kafka.PartitionAny
```

GoLand correctly sees this dependency and does not report any errors. But build does not work.

My **go env** output:

```
go env                                                                                                                   ﳑ in powershell at 11:51:17
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\fjod\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\fjod\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\fjod\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\fjod\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.20.5
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=0
set GOMOD=F:\work\kafka\kafka_dotnet_golang\src\golang\kafka-go-producer\go.mod
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_FFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-O2 -g
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\fjod\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build3429863524=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

I tried reinstalling go and followed tutorial from scratch 3 times. No matter what I try, I have never seen *github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka*  in my **go list** output.

EDIT1: I tried using [this example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/importing-packages-in-go) to check if I can use modules at all, and simple program with  github.com/google/uuid module works fine. Looks like it's kafka-related problem :/

Comment: How you imported the package `github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go` in your `producer.go`?. See this example https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/avro_generic_producer_example/avro_generic_producer_example.go

Comment: `CGO_ENABLED` should be set to `1` because the package is a wrapper of a C library. And the C compiler specified with `CC` should be available on the system (which is not available on Windows most of the time).

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC yes, I copy-pasted examples from here https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/go/#build-producer

Comment: As `Zeke Lu` mentioned, The issue is with 'CGO_ENABLED'.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it should now work at all :
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/889

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/128

In the end, I created a project in WSL and continued studying.